# Past tense and future tense can be used together?

Tags: american-english, british-english

For example, They told me that they will support our next event.

Can these 2 tenses be together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining past and future tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115070/combining-past-and-future-tense)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Si Pra.  I believe our sister site ell.stackexchange.com would probably be more appropriate for you.

Comment: @divibisan  Thank you so much. 

Comment: @Centaurus Than you so much. 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes they can, as long as the event is still to come.